# append %200 at the end of an "address 1.1.1.1" line

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed

I need to add `%200` at the end if "address 1.1.1.1". I am using bash on linux if someone can let me know.

## Current

```
ltm node /test/10.90.0.1 {
    address 10.90.0.1
}
ltm node /test/10.90.0.12 {
    address 10.90.0.12
}

ltm node /test/10.90.0.50 {
address 10.90.0.50      
}
```

## Desired, with insertion of `%200`

```
ltm node /test/10.90.0.1 {
    address 10.90.0.1%200
}
ltm node /test/10.90.0.12 {
    address 10.90.0.12%200   
}
ltm node /test/10.90.0.50 {
    address 10.90.0.50%200
}
```

Comment: Your desired output does not match the description; none of the "node"s are have an apparent address of 1.1.1.1.

Comment: yeah that was an example the current and desired format below to add %200 after the ip address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose this with `awk`:

```
awk '/address/ && sub("$","%200") || 1' file.txt
```

or with `sed`:

```
sed '/address/ s/$/%200/' file.txt
```

If you use the option `-i` you will directly edit your file.

Comment: thx that worked

Answer (score 2):

This achieves what you're requesting.

```
sed 's/address.*/&%200/' current.txt
```

Example:

```
$ sed 's/address.*/&%200/' current.txt
ltm node /test/10.90.0.1 {
    address 10.90.0.1%200
}
ltm node /test/10.90.0.12 {
    address 10.90.0.12%200
}

ltm node /test/10.90.0.50 {
address 10.90.0.50%200
}
$
```